# Execute .NET Core 3.1 background worker tasks simultaneously

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, .net-core

I have following code:

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{

    public Worker()
    {
    }

    protected async override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var task1 = Task.Run(() =>
                MethodOneAsync(stoppingToken)
            ).ContinueWith(_ => Debug.WriteLine($"MethodOneAsync finished @ {DateTime.Now:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffff}"));
            var task2 = Task.Run(() =>
                MethodTwoAsync(stoppingToken)
            ).ContinueWith(_ => Debug.WriteLine($"MethodTwoAsync finished @ {DateTime.Now:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffff}"));

            await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);

            await Task.Delay(10000);
        }
    }

    private async Task<bool> MethodOneAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"MethodOneAsync started @ {DateTime.Now:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffff}");
        await Task.Delay(1000); // emulating some long work

        return true;
    }

    private async Task<bool> MethodTwoAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"MethodTwoAsync started @ {DateTime.Now:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffff}");
        await Task.Delay(1000); // emulating some long work

        return true;
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is:

- to create background worker that will call MethodOneAsync and MethodTwoAsync on separate threads (start both tasks simultaneously)
- log time each task started and finished
- wait for them both to finish
- then wait another 10 seconds
- repeat all over again

The code I wrote does its job as expected.
Since I am still trying to get a grasp of .NET Core tasks, I would like to know is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Are `MethodOneAsync` and `MethodTwoAsync` CPU-bound or IO-bound?

Comment: They get a list of objects from SQL, map them to MongoDB objects, and update MongoDB with new objects. So, mostly IO-bound.

Comment: Then you don't need `Task.Run` calls in the `ExecuteAsync`. You could simply call `await Task.WhenAll(MethodOneAsync(stoppingToken), MethodTwoAsync(stoppingToken));`

Comment: @PeterCsala can you please, in short, tell why?

Comment: `Task.Run` was designed for CPU-bound work, so it pulls a thread from the thread pool to run the method and returns a Task which represents the completion. Async non-blocking I/O operation does not need a dedicated thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Async method out-of-the-box is using multiple threads for continuations. (Everything after `await` is continuation). Exception of this rule if existing `SynchronizationContext`. Don't `Task.Run` asynchronous I/O-bound operation, do it only for synchronous CPU-bound one. [Asynchronous programming](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async), [SynchrinizationContext & TaskScheduler](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/).
- Mixing `.ContinueWith` and `await` is not recommended as it doing the same but using different coding pattern. Mixing patterns with no reason makes the code more complicated.

If I were you, the code could look like this:

```cs
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    protected async override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        // all methods will throw OperationCanceledException if cancellation was happened,
        // then checking if it was canceled is a kind of redundancy here.
        while (true) 
        {
            var task1 = MethodOneAsync(stoppingToken);
            var task2 = MethodTwoAsync(stoppingToken);
            await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken)); // inlining Task.Delay here changes the logic: 10 seconds counted between starts of two iterations not between finish of previous and start of next.
        }
    }

    private async Task MethodOneAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"MethodOneAsync started @ {DateTime.Now:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffff}");
        await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        Debug.WriteLine($"MethodOneAsync finished @ {DateTime.Now:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffff}");
    }

    private async Task MethodTwoAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"MethodTwoAsync started @ {DateTime.Now:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffff}");
        await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        Debug.WriteLine($"MethodTwoAsync finished @ {DateTime.Now:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffff}");
    }
}
```

About `Worker` class purpose. It looks like `Scheduler` not `Worker` because it repeats some work continuously. Consider to change its name.